# Domestic Rabbit Abandoned her litter

Tags: health, diet, rabbits, feeding, breeding

My Female show Florida White has starting "unintentional harming" her litters, I believe she is doing this while the cleaning them after birth. We managed to save 2 out of 5. We have been holding our momma Lop (her litter is 4 weeks old so they are too old to place these little ones with her) and holding the other babies to her while they feed. Mind you the newborns were born 3/26/16 and today is 3/29/16. We have managed to keep them going for this long. Just wondering if there is anything else I can do to increase chance of survival?

Side note my children raise FFA breeding rabbits.

Comment: I am assuming you had a shelf where mom could get away from the babies (moms will hurt the kits, if she can't get away from them).  Is it possible to place the babies back with mom for a few minutes once or twice a day (with supervision) so they can nurse from her?

Comment: I have been doing that also. yes we use nesting boxes. I will try that and see what she does. Thank you for helping. Have never had this issue.

Comment: If putting them in to nurse with mom, works please post it as an answer you question.  Others will benefit from it in the future, include any details that you find important.